# how to write out entire months with object key where the months are in numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lit

Currently I'm slightly confused why my code is not working as intended, and I was hoping you guys would be able to help me.

I have an object with year and months.

```
chosenMonths = {[
    2022: [0,1,2]
    2018: [9,10]
    2017: [11]
]}
```

I have a function that will convert the number into written out months:

```
const writeOutMonth = function(num, locale) {
    const date = new Date();
    date.setMonth(num);

    return date.toLocaleString(locale, {month: 'long',});
}
```

And inside my code I have an Object.keys where I want to print out the year and then the written out months on the page.

```
${Object.keys(chosenMonths).reverse().map((year) => html`<p1> ${year}: ${writeOutMonth(chosenMonth[year].sort().join(', '), 'en-gb')}</p>`)}
```

Right now, I see it will render:

```
2022: Invalid Date
2021: Invalid Date
2017: December
```

My question is: why is it Invalid Date, when I have multiple numbers in a year, and how do I make it work?

Comment: `chosenMonths` is invalid syntax. When I run it I get a SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'.

Comment: Regarding the question, what do you expect `Date` to do when you call `setMonth('0,1,2')`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey, at first I thought it would choose 0 first, and then go to 1 and then 2, but I'm guessing that's not the case as it's only working for single digit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to made modifications to make the code run, I believe that's what you need, the problem was that you were passing a string composed of months, instead of passing a month, I change the method to receive an array og months, also, to the sort() I had to the add the sorting function

```
chosenMonths = {
  2022: [0, 1, 2],
  2018: [9, 10],
  2017: [11],
};

const writeOutMonth = function (monthArray, locale) {
  let monthNames = [];

  monthArray.forEach((mon) => {
    const date = new Date();
    date.setMonth(mon);
    monthNames.push(date.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" }));
  });

  return monthNames.join(", ");
};

let result = Object.keys(chosenMonths)
  .reverse()
  .map(
    (year) =>
      `<p1> ${year}: ${writeOutMonth(
        chosenMonths[year].sort((a, b) => a - b),
        "en-gb"
      )}</p>`
  );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me! Could you explain to me what the (a, b) => a - b) does? I don't understand this yet

Comment: The default sorting behaviour of the sort() is to sort alphabetically. So for instance, the array: [1, 0, 2,10] would be sorted as [0, 1, 10, 2].  To sort numericaly you will have to pass a function that the method will use to sort. I don't know the exact details also =D, it's like the method subtracts one element to the other to see which is greater and order